# How to combine/connect Arabic letters from isolated form to connected form?

Tags: c#, arabic

I'm trying to combine/connect Arabic letters coming from a string.

The issue with this language and others is that each letter has 4 ways of being displayed, Isolated, Initial, Medial and final.

I've read a lot about the issue but didn't understand if there is a solution or not.

I have this text: **مرحبا** (which means "Marhaba" - Hello), it's read from right to left.

I'm developing a plug-in for another program which gives me the same string connected but backwards like this: **ابحرم** (if we read it from LTR it's ok but it should be RTL), so I separate the chars and reverse them, but then when I draw them on screen (graphics app) they are being displayed in their Isolated form like so: **م ر ح ب ا** reading fine from RTL but not connected.

So I was trying many things to make them display on the screen in the connected form but didn't get it to work, is there a simple method that I could use to connect them when displayed?

Thanks in advance.

My code for reversing the letters is:

```
    TextElementEnumerator enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(stringFromApp);

    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        elements.Add(enumerator.GetTextElement());

    elements.Reverse();
    string reversed = string.Concat(elements);
    App.textObject.text = reversed;
```

Comment: plz show your code

Comment: My crystal ball says that it only *looks* reversed.  And that reversing it screws up the text rendering engine.  Be sure that whatever window you display it in has the RightToLeft property set to Yes.  If necessary prefix "\u200f".

Comment: @HansPassant I like your crystal ball, sounds like a good solution, I'll try it soon and update here.

Comment: In Photoshop when I see Arabic letters not connected like you described, I change the text rendering engine and it shows right, I think Hans Passant crystal ball is right. Also try to change the font, `Times New Roman` may work.

Comment: what is a crystal ball?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help you .

```
// Specify Arabic script Unicode ranges
const int arabicStart = 0x0600;
const int arabicEnd = 0x06FF;

private char MapArabicCharacter(char originalChar, int charIndex, int firstCharIndex, int lastCharIndex)
{
    // Check if the character is Arabic
    if (IsArabicCharacter(originalChar))
    {
        // If the character is the first or last character in the text, return the isolated form
        if (charIndex == firstCharIndex || charIndex == lastCharIndex)
        {
            // Return the isolated form of the character
            // Note: This is a simplified approach and may not handle all cases correctly
            return GetIsolatedForm(originalChar);
        }
    }

    // If the character is not Arabic or does not meet the above conditions, return the original character
    return originalChar;
}

// Function to check if a character is Arabic
private bool IsArabicCharacter(char c)
{
    // Check if the character falls within the Arabic Unicode range
    return (c >= arabicStart && c <= arabicEnd);
}

// Function to get the isolated form of an Arabic character
private char GetIsolatedForm(char c)
{
    // Add logic to return the isolated form of the character
    // This is a simplified example and may not handle all cases correctly
    // For demonstration purposes, we'll just return the character itself
    return c;
}
```

And to use it

```
TextElementEnumerator enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(stringFromApp);

List<char> mappedChars = new List<char>();
int charIndex = 0;
int lastCharIndex = stringFromApp.Length - 1;

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    char originalChar = enumerator.GetTextElement()[0];
    char mappedChar = MapArabicCharacter(originalChar, charIndex, 0, lastCharIndex);
    mappedChars.Add(mappedChar);
    charIndex++;
}

mappedChars.Reverse();
string reversed = new string(mappedChars.ToArray());
App.textObject.text = reversed;
```